# Identifying (grouping?) and terminating stray (detached) processes in Java

Tags: java, cross-platform, integration-testing, external-process, process-management

My integration tests in Maven require to start some external processes (servers). If the user aborts the maven process, those processes continue to linger around. I used to add a 'key' (ie. BUILD_ARTIFACT_PROCID=xyz) to the environment of those processes so I could identify them via a BASH script, relying on cygwin on Windows systems.

However, some servers spawn their own childs not propagating the environment variables or their processes not registering under cygwin's /proc.

This general problem now persists for decades and there seems to be still no cross-platform solution to it.

Anyone able to give me a working, proper solution, ie one that does not rely on potentially stale PID files, that also might be useless if an intermediary process is missing? How do you guys solve that problem?

Comment: Take a look at `jps` also [Apache Daemon](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/jsvc.html) and `jsvc` and [`procrun`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html).

Comment: that stuff is more about hooking up with the OS, not about low level process identification. even my solution using an environment tag variable has a slight chance of race condition where the process gets replaced by a new process having the same pid between me finding the process via /proc and sending the kill signal.